# iptables dynamic NAT, SNAT: force overload on exhaustion

Tags: iptables, firewall, ip, nat

Is there a way to specify the use of iptables NAT'ing where you can use SNAT for a pool of outside addresses, but when the last IP is about to be used it is used as an overloaded outside IP? I remember hearing about this with Cisco equipment. But as unsure how to craft it as iptables.

So if I have a outside pool of 1.1.1.1/29 giving me 6 IPs. Could I do a SNAT iptable rule for 5 of them and an masquerade for the last?

Assuming I have a /24 on the inside.

-Jim